# Modify Laravel request before insert

Tags: laravel, post, laravel-request

Is is possible to modify a request before it gets inserted into the database?

```
  public function store(StoreRequest $request)
        {
           $request->date_posted = strtotime($request->date_posted);
           //insert data here.
        }
```

Comment: Requests have a `merge` function to add/modify data (and several other functions), but a raw request doesn't typically *get* inserted directly. Typically there's going to be a model of some sort that gets populated with the request's data via `fill`, so just after the `fill` call you'd update the model before saving.

Comment: what you have above works perfectly fine. so yes it can be

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution maybe can resolve your issue .
 Add setter in model so it will be look like this

```
Class ModelX {
      public function setDateDatePosted Attribute($date_posted)
        {
            $this->attributes['date_posted'] = strtotime($date_posted);
        }
}
```

hope it useful for you .

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be, what you have works perfectly fine

```
public function store(StoreRequest $request)
    {
       $request->date_posted = strtotime($request->date_posted);
       or
       $datePosted = $request->date_posted + 2;
       $datePosted = $request->date_posted . 'some other addons';
       //insert data here.
    }
```

these are just examples but i hope you get what im saying.

Fyi if you input into the db, the created_at and updated_at will update and so you don't need to insert the time the post was made manually.